# are there ways to improve the performance of Fortune's algorithm if the sites can only be placed on integer coordinates?

Tags: computational-geometry, voronoi

I'm working on a mobile game for tablets that has players strategizing about the placement of sites in a Voronoi diagram, for background. after 17 sites have been placed the game progresses to it next phase, and my code runs Fortune's algorithm to calculate the cells. all the sites must be integer coordinates between 1 and 8, and it uses Manhattan distance instead of Euclidian. can that property be used to improve the runtime of Fortune's algorithm?

Comment: Is finding the Voronoi diagram of 17 sites really the performance bottleneck of your application currently? How much time does it take?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bottleneck, but it is a feedback item from my playtesters. I'm running it on an Android tablet with 2.4 Ghz cpu and it's taking over 3 minutes to complete.

Comment: You have implemented the algorithm incorrectly, then. Three minutes would be reasonable for *billions* of sites.

Comment: okay, I'll take a look at my code to see if there is something redundant, it is creating the diagram correctly, so it may just be overcalculating.

Comment: This paper by Mark Overmars gives you a taste of what can be achieved with integer coordinates: "Computational geometry on a grid an overview" (though it does not address Voronoi).

Comment: Indeed, 3 minutes for 17 sites is completely astronomic. I would expect below a millisecond with an efficient algorithm, and below a second for inefficient ones. By the way, 17 sites on 64 possible nodes seems very crowded !